# PDFBox setOpenAction to print

Tags: javascript, java, printing, pdfbox

I'm new to PDFBox, I have a requirement to send the PDF to the printer when it is opened. We are using PDFBox api to generate the PDFs. I have used the below code to try setting the action on open but nothing worked. Please help.
I have used different javascript like window.print(); this.print(); print();

```
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDActionJavaScript javascript=new PDActionJavaScript("app.print();");
    doc.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(javascript);
```

Comment: try this PDActionJavaScript("this.print({bUI: false, bSilent: true, bShrinkToFit: true});");

Comment: This worked... Thank you so much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this PDActionJavaScript("this.print({bUI: false, bSilent: true, bShrinkToFit: true});");

Comment: can you explain what this function does?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without JS:

```
    PDActionNamed action = new PDActionNamed();
    action.setN("Print");
    doc.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(action);
```